# Java SWT Resize Tripple SashForm constant middle smoothly

Tags: java, resize, swt

I implemented a Java SWT SashForm with 3 panes:

```
SashForm oSash = new SashForm(cmptParent, SWT.NONE);
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
oSash.setLayout(gridLayout);
oSash.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

Composite oPaneLeft = new Composite(oSash, SWT.NONE);
...
Composite oPaneMiddle = new Composite(oSash, SWT.NONE);
...
Composite oPaneRight = new Composite(oSash, SWT.NONE);
```

The idea is to have a fixed size middle partition. Setting up initial widths is simple.

I want to be be able to resize the form by dragging the middle. The user clicks on the middle and drags left or right, thereby keeping the middle pane fixed, just sliding left or right. I am able to implement this functionality as follows:

```
private static Boolean sisResizeSashMiddle = false;
private static int siPosSashMiddleOffset = 0;

...

cmptPaneMiddle = new Composite(cmptParent, SWT.NONE);
cmptPaneMiddle.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        // The user wishes to resize the sash.
        AppMain.sisResizeSashMiddle = true;
        AppMain.siPosSashMiddleOffset = arg0.x - AppMain.siPosSashMiddleStart;
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        // The user finished resizing the sash.
        AppMain.sisResizeSashMiddle = false;
    }
});
cmptPaneMiddle.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener()
{
    public void mouseMove(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        // Only resize the sashes if user hold down the mouse while dragging.
        if (true == AppMain.sisResizeSashMiddle)
        {
            // Compute the width of each sash.
            int icxShell = shell.getSize().x;
            int icxLeft = arg0.x - AppMain.siPosSashMiddleOffset;
            int icxMiddle = AppMain.BrowserSash_Pane_Middle_Width;
            int icxRight = shell.getSize().x - icxLeft - icxMiddle;

            // Compute the weights.
            int iWeightLeft = 10000 * icxLeft / icxShell;
            int iWeightMiddle = 10000 * icxMiddle / icxShell;
            int iWeightRight = 10000 * icxRight / icxShell;

            // Set the weights.
        int[] weights = new int[] {iWeightLeft, iWeightMiddle, iWeightRight};
        oSash.setWeights(weights);
        }
    }
});
```

My issue is that sliding implementation is jerky and jittery, definitely not smooth. Is there a better way to get the same effect, just smooth with no jerky behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `SWT.SMOOTH` flag on the `SashForm`:

```
SashForm oSash = new SashForm(cmptParent, SWT.SMOOTH);
```

Comment: That addition improved things a bit, but I still see the jerky behavior, not to mention the going back and forth, like the control tries to fight my movement. That probably has to do with the weight attribute being an integer. Actually, IMHO the whole "weight" concept is flawed in this case. I should just be able to specify the size of each sash.